# Touchpad button assignments don't persist with Lenovo T400 on WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, touchpad, thinkpad, remapping, wake-up

I have a Lenovo T400 notebook with Windows XP on it.  I usually use the TrackPoint, and almost never use the TouchPad.  I do a look of work on Linux over VNC, in my setup the middle mouse button is mapped to "paste".

Considering that the notebook doesn't really have a middle button (it's only a scrolling button) I mapped the unused left button of the TouchPad to be a middle button.  However, when I send the computer to Standby and bring it out, the left button reverts to being a left button, not a middle one.

How can I make sure that the mapping persists?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the scrolling feature of that middle button off, and it becomes the middle click you want.  See this question for details: [thinkpad middle click](https://superuser.com/questions/35970/thinkpad-x30-middle-click/36231#36231)

Comment: The problem isn't how to emulate a middle click.  The problem is how to make it persist.  The setting keeps on reverting to the default.

Comment: I tried it on my t61p, and it worked fine.  Ultranav seems to have been updated for the t400s machines (2.05 June 2009).  You may want to try a newer version to see if it fixes the problem.