# Middle-click on Lenovo laptop

Tags: mouse, thinkpad

I just got myself a new Lenovo T400 laptop and I'm quite enjoying it.  However, I'm kind of a middle click junky, it gets used on my desktop probably more than Right-click.  Anyway, on other laptops I have been able to use Right Click + Left Click to emulate a middle click.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: If you want to use the 3 mouse buttons below the keyboard, then check out this question: http://superuser.com/questions/35970/thinkpad-x30-middle-click/36231#36231

Answer (score 4):

With Windows 10, the Mouse part of the new Settings app has an "ELAN TrackPoint for Thinkpad" heading (which can also be accessed just by typing e.g. "trackpoint" with Start menu open). This leads to a "TrackPoint settings" link, and there the Middle Button Action dropdown menu can be changed from Scrolling to Middle Click.

Answer (score 3):

Update your synaptics touchpad driver - there should be an option to set corners as middle-click.

I've not been following synaptics driver development - it could be that now there's an option for two-button-middle-click-emulation too.

Update : 2-button-middle-click-emulation found for T400 [here](http://log.psi.cc/2009/04/09/two-button-middle-click-on-a-lenovo-t400-t500/).

Comment: The T400 does not have a Synaptics touchpad... See http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-72858#mouse

Comment: Update : 2-button-middle-click-emulation found. :) http://log.psi.cc/2009/04/09/two-button-middle-click-on-a-lenovo-t400-t500/

Comment: Not too sure about US or EU or anywhere else, but the T400 sitting in my office works with the Synaptics driver.

Comment: @Breakthrough - Just because you don't see Synaptics software listed on the T400 support site, does not mean that they don't use Synaptics touchpads. Have you seen an Ultranav touchpad brand anywhere else then besides on Lenovo? Are you saying that they created a company called Ultranav just to make touchpads for their own notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

On ThinkPad t400s **Windows 7** works for me disabling of special functions on a middle button:

Control Panel -> Mouse -> UltraNav (tab) -> TrackPoint "Settings..." (button) -> Set "Choose Scrolling or Magnifying Glass Function" to "Neither"

On **Windows 8** one suggest to uninstall driver for UltraNav pointing device completely and use native Windows 8 support: Delete driver for UltraNav pointing device completely.
see: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Carbon-X1-Use-middle-scroll-button-as-middle-click/m-p/1413823#M54804

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the touchpad at all, so I configured the left touchpad button to be a middle button.  You can do this in Control Panel | Mouse | UltraNav.

Note that I have [this](https://superuser.com/questions/20337/touchpad-button-assignments-dont-persist-with-lenovo-t400-on-winxp) problem that is still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey(.com) could do this quite easily.

```
LButton & RButton::MButton
```

would do middle on clicking left then right. You could also remap right then left to middle, or something totally different.

edit: I see I got the example the ENTIRELY wrong way round. The way & works is that if you press and hold button 1, then press button 2, it fires - so... yeah. :D